# How to read Mdat atoms of a mp4 video?

Tags: python, go, parsing, mp4

I am trying to parse a mp4 and able to do parse `moov` but not sure how to use `moov` information to parse `mdat`.

My goal is to get the track info like metadata and if possible frames from `mdat` as it contains the video and audio data.

currently following [QuickTime File Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-33303)

Tried with `Sample-to-Chunk Atoms` but all my stsc (20 bytes) looks like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 1]
```

```
    fmt.Println(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[0:4])) //4
    fmt.Println(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[4:8])) //4
    fmt.Println(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[8:16])) //8
    fmt.Println(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[16:20])) //4
```

Don't know currently how to approach and parse `mdat` atoms.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try this lib? https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/abema/go-mp4

Comment: If not you can try to define your structures and use this to parse: https://nicedoc.io/ghostiam/binstruct

Comment: @code0x00 Try reading as `buf[0:3]` and `buf[4:7]` etc...? Your first four bytes are `[0] [1] [2] [3]` so why read up to `[4]`?

Answer (score 0):

the mp4 specification is ISO/IEC 14496-12 which is more definitive than the qt one.

If you want to understand how the sample tables reference individual frames you could look at my project here https://github.com/essential61/mp4analyser